# PowerShell - Select secondary drive for install

Tags: powershell

I have the following installation script that assigns the drive letter if the test-path is true. All our applications are installed on the secondary disk and never the same as the OS (C:).

```
$DeviceDrive = "C:"
Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType=3 AND DeviceID!='C:'" |
Where-Object { Test-Path "$($_.DeviceID)\Apps\" } |
Foreach-Object {
    $DeviceDrive = $_.DeviceID
}
```

The path may not exist if it is a new host and I don't want the default drive to be `C:`. If the path doesn't exist, how would I assign the secondary disk (i.e D:) to `$DeviceDrive` variable? Note, there may be more then 2 drives and the secondary disk may not be D: i.e. could be F: or even G:. It also needs to work on powershell v2.0 because of 2003 hosts.

I need something along the lines

```
IF ($Devicedrive -eq "C:"){
# Select secondary disk and assign to $Devicedrive}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will get a root, `D:\` for example, of the drive in the manner you specified.  I verified it worked on PowerShell 5 and 2.  I assume you can integrate this into the rest of your script.

```
$roots =  @(Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | where-object { $_.free -gt 1GB} | Sort-Object -Property Root | Select-Object -First 2 -ExpandProperty root)    if($roots.count -eq 2 -and $roots[0] -eq 'C:\')
{
    $root=$roots[1]
}
else
{
    $root=$roots[0]
}
```

Thanks,
Travis

Updated on 6/4/2016 to address comments

Comment: this keeps assigning the A: to $root. I need it to be secondary the disk.

Comment: is it possible to exclude roots that dont show Used/Free GB?

Comment: I believe this could work for me, `$roots = @(Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Where-Object {$_.Free -gt 300MB} | Sort-Object -Property Root | Select-Object -First 2 -ExpandProperty root)
if($roots.count -eq 2 -and $roots[0] -eq 'C:\')
{
    $root=$roots[1]
}
else
{
    $root=$roots[0]
}`

Comment: @DineshK I updated the sample to address the A: issue.